# bind Kendo vue dropdownlist to array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding, kendo-ui

**SAMPLE** https://stackblitz.com/edit/usjgwp?file=index.html

I want to show a number of kendo `dropdownlist`(s) on a page. The exact number depends on an API call. This API call will give me an array of stakeholder objects. Stakeholder objects have the following properties: Id, name, type, role and isSelected.

The number of `dropdownlist` that has to be shown on this page should be equal to the number of unique `type` values in the API response array. i.e,
 `numberOfDropdowns = stakeholders.map(a => a.type).distinct().count()`.

Now, each dropdown will have a `datasource` based on the `type` property. i.e, For a dropdown for `type = 1`, dataSource will be `stakeholders.filter(s => s.type == 1)`.

Also the default values in the dropdowns will be based on the `isSelected` property. For every `type`, only one object will have `isSelected = true`.

I have achieved these things by using the following code:

```
<template>
  <div
    v-if="selectedStakeholders.length > 0"
    v-for="(stakeholderLabel, index) in stakeholderLabels"
    :key="stakeholderLabel.Key"
  >
    <label>{{ stakeholderLabel.Value }}:</label>
    <kendo-dropdownlist
      v-model="selectedStakeholders[index].Id"
      :data-source="stakeholders.filter(s => s.type == stakeholderLabel.Key)"
      data-text-field="name"
      data-value-field="Id"
    ></kendo-dropdownlist>

    <button @click="updateStakeholders">Update form</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import STAKEHOLDER_SERVICE from "somePath";
export default {
  name: "someName",
  props: {
    value1: String,
    value2: String,    
  },
  data() {
    return {
      payload: {
        value1: this.value1,
        value2: this.value2
      },
      stakeholders: [],
      selectedStakeholders: [],
      stakeholderLabels: [] // [{Key: 1, Value: "Stakeholder1"}, {Key: 2, Value: "Stakeholder2"}, ... ]
    };
  },
  mounted: async function() {
    await this.setStakeholderLabels();
    await this.setStakeholderDataSource();
    this.setSelectedStakeholdersArray();
  },
  methods: {   
    async setStakeholderLabels() {
      let kvPairs = await STAKEHOLDER_SERVICE.getStakeholderLabels();
      kvPairs = kvPairs.sort((kv1, kv2) => (kv1.Key > kv2.Key ? 1 : -1));
      kvPairs.forEach(kvPair => this.stakeholderLabels.push(kvPair));
        },
    async setStakeholderDataSource() {
      this.stakeholders = await STAKEHOLDER_SERVICE.getStakeholders(
        this.payload
      );
    }
    setSelectedStakeholdersArray() {
      const selectedStakeholders = this.stakeholders
        .filter(s => s.isSelected === true)
                .sort((s1, s2) => (s1.type > s2.type ? 1 : -1));

      selectedStakeholders.forEach(selectedStakeholder =>
        this.selectedStakeholders.push(selectedStakeholder)
      );      
    },
    async updateStakeholders() {
      console.log(this.selectedStakeholders);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The problem is that I am not able to change the selection in the `dropdownlist` the selection always remains the same as the default selected values. Even when I choose a different option in any `dropdownlist`, the selection does not actually change.

I've also tried binding like this:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist
      v-model="selectedStakeholders[index]"
            value-primitive="false"
      :data-source="stakeholders.filter(s => s.type == stakeholderLabel.Key)"
      data-text-field="name"
      data-value-field="Id"
    ></kendo-dropdownlist>
```

If I bind like this, I am able to change selection but then the default selection does not happen, the first option is always the selection option i.e, default selection is not based on the `isSelected` property.

My requirement is that I have to show the `dropdown` with some default selections, allow the user to choose different options in all the different dropdowns and then retrieve all the selection then the update button is clicked.

**UPDATE**:
When I use the first method for binding, The `Id` property of objects in the `selectedStakeholders` array is actually changing, but it does not reflect on the UI, i.e, on the UI, the selected option is always the default option even when user changes selection.
Also when I subscribe to the `change` and `select` events, I see that only select event is being triggered, change event never triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that it was a Vue.js limitation (or a JS limitation which vue inherited),
[Link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)

I had to explicitly change the values in `selectedStakeholders` array like this:

```
<template>
  <div
    v-if="selectedStakeholders.length > 0"
    v-for="(stakeholderLabel, index) in stakeholderLabels"
    :key="stakeholderLabel.Key"
  >
    <label>{{ stakeholderLabel.Value }}:</label>
    <kendo-dropdownlist
      v-model="selectedStakeholders[index].Id"
      :data-source="stakeholders.filter(s => s.type == stakeholderLabel.Key)"
      data-text-field="name"
      data-value-field="Id"
      @select="selected"
    ></kendo-dropdownlist>

    <button @click="updateStakeholders">Update form</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

And in methods:

```
selected(e) {
      const stakeholderTypeId = e.dataItem.type;
      const selectedStakeholderIndexForTypeId = this.selectedStakeholders.findIndex(
        s => s.type == stakeholderTypeId
      );
      this.$set(
        this.selectedStakeholders,
        selectedStakeholderIndexForTypeId,
        e.dataItem
      );
    }
```